# How to get a polygon from a postcode?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a way to draw a polygon from a postcode or alternatively all postcode coordinates to draw the polygon.
I searched for a long time but I have not found anything.
Can someone help me?

Thank you very much

**Edit:** I need for UK and I found this archive: google.com/fusiontables/… Now, the question is: how I can use this data with my google map?

Comment: What country?  For the US [zipcode polygons are available in FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html)

Comment: The Ordnance Survey provide a free list of all postcodes in the UK as part of their CodePoint Open data. Coordinates are as Northings/Eastings, but can easily be converted to OSGB36  Lat/Long, and from there to WGS84 Lat/Long coordinates... these coordinates are a centrepoint for each individual postcode, not a polygon; but you can create a polygon from individual postcodes for different postal zones

Comment: I need for UK and I found this archive: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1jgWYtlqGSPzlIa-is8wl1cZkVIWEm_89rWUwqFU

Now, the question is: how I can use this data with my google map?

Comment: What have you tried?  It sounds like you just want to display a postcode (or a few postcodes) on a map.  Have you looked at [FusionTablesLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)?

Comment: I just wish to display polygon when a user type a postcode.
Using the csv file presents in the link I posted above I can know all coordinates of a postcode and draw a polygon, right?

Comment: Yes.  Or you can use a FusionTablesLayer to display that FusionTable (or your own copy of it) with the appropriate query to show just the postcode the user requested.

Comment: @geocodezip I don't understand why some fields start with "<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>" and some others with "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>".
How I can correctly parse this file?

Comment: The Area Data is KML geometry definitions. Those are defined in the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference). A MultiGeometry allows multiple Polygons in the same object (for a postcode that contains several separate polygons).  I would think you would be better off using a FusionTablesLayer to render the polygon on the map, as that can already handle this format of data.

Comment: @geocodezip I'm not being able to use KML Reference. I try to import csv file in my MySQL db. If you can give a little example about how to use those references it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You can download my free php class concave-hull @ phpclasses.org. You can find an example at http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence/. Or you can download shapefiles from you country and compute the center of gravity and use it for the postcode:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71643/map-projection-lat-lon-to-pixel.

Comment: Surely the first thing OP needs is a list of postcode coordinates to get the polygons/shapefiles. He's identified a source of kml files, will your class work with those?

Comment: Please use his full name (@MarkBaker) to call him, otherwise he won't be notified.

Answer (score -1):

there is no correspondance between zipcodes and geographical polygons. You can know if a given address belongs to a particular zipcode, but cannot know which polygon contains all addresses of a given zipcode.

Even if you had every address inside a given zipcode, and its corresponding coordinates, calculating the hull would result in a smaller polygon than reality, disjoint from the closest one.

The real polygon, it there was one, shouldn't have it vertexes at addresses, but in between an address of its own and the closest addresss of the adjacent polygon.

What I have done, and it's a gross approximation, it relating each block to its  ZCTA from census bureau and calculate a ZCTA geometry ad the union of all its blocks. ZCTA are different from USPS zipcodes, but they are acceptably similar for most use cases.